# Determine the correct capacitors value

Tags: capacitor, avr, atmega

what the right way to determine the correct capacitors value needed for a avr-chip with a crystal oscillator?

Let say the crystal's load capacitance is: 20pF

and i want to use: atmega8-16pu

what should i look for and what the math behind it?

please don't just tell me to use 2x22pF capacitor. I'm not here to do my homework, but to

understand it for future use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [AVR042](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-2521-avr-hardware-design-considerations_applicationnote_avr042.pdf), "AVR Hardware Design Considerations", section 4, "Using crystal and ceramic resonators", subsection 2, "General about crystals and ceramic resonators":

> \$C = 2 ⋅ C_L − C_S\$
>
> (C<sub>S</sub> can be estimated to be 5pF - 10pF)

So, about 30pF.

Comment: Wh it estimated to 5pF - 10pF? why not something more accurate ? why would i pick 5 instead of 10 or opposite ?

Comment: That would depend on how you've laid out the board and what it's made of.

Comment: okay, how did you guess about 30pF?

Comment: I took the high end of the estimate of the stray capacitance and plugged it into the equation.

Comment: what is the reason behind that choice?

Comment: Pure pessimism.

Comment: Is there any benefit in that?

Comment: Nope. You should always get a reasonable measurement and work from there.

Comment: Alright is 30pF for both cap or single one?

Comment: That is for each capacitor.

Comment: can "CS" be calculated more accurate if yes, what equation should i try to solve ?

Comment: It's all in AVR042.

Comment: English is not my mother tongue. Do you mind pointing it out please?

Comment: Section 4.2, as mentioned.

Comment: I already searched it and found something, but becouse my leak of english understanding i was hoping you could confirm which one and explain what to do so i could try myself.

Comment: It starts in the paragraph before equation 4-1 and ends with equation 4-2.